# How can i access the uploaded file in the form given below, i'm getting undefined index error

Tags: php

The form

```
<form action="adminhandler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product name">Enter product name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="" name="productname">

              </div> 
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product name">Select product category</label>
                <select name="select" class=" custom-select">
                  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                  <option value="1">Formal Shoes</option>
                  <option value="2">Sneakers</option>
                  <option value="3">Tracksuits</option>
                  <option value="3">Clothing</option>
                  <option value="3">Accessories</option>
                </select>

              </div> 
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product price">Enter product price(Naira)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productPrice" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder=""
                name="price">

              </div> 
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
                 <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="rogue">
               </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

My php code

```
$new=($_FILES['rogue']['name']);
         print_r($new);
```

The exact error code is "Notice: Undefined index: rogue in C:\xampp\htdocs\eshop\data\adminhandler.php on line 13"

Comment: try `print_r($_FILES)` and you will see.

Comment: This helped a lot..the file input name wasn't updating previously..Thanks